# Ethereum Bases for Account Creation

Tags: wallets, accounts

I came in contact with Ethereum and I'd like to know the inner workings of it, for example, what is the purpose of it inside an app or web application, and where accounts and wallets are made. Also, is there an specific site for that to be done, and how ETH can connect with the transations that we are familiarized with. I think this a question fundamentals on it.

Comment: the contract is outside the dApp, it is in the chain while the dApp is in your browser or server

Answer (score 2):

An Ethereum account is a cryptographically secure random 256-bit integer, also known as a private key in [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Wallets are just a collection of accounts.

A good learning material inner working for Ethereum accounts is the source code of [eth_account Python package](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html).